# Will renaming a solution in Visual Studio break everything?

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I'm using Visual Studio 2005 and I'm wondering what will happen if I rename my solution file from **prefs.sln** to **someOtherFilename.sln**, will completely mess things up? Pretty simple question, but I wanted to ask before I went ahead and did anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will still work. I've never had an issue renaming a **Solution** file.

Incidentally, you can rename a **Project** file as well, but when you do that, some settings may not make sense to a future developer - things like the default project Namespace come to mind.  Everything still works, but it's something to bear in mind when you run across error messages and issues trying to reference classes within the project.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, it shouldn't break anything. Practically, you should be using source control and never be afraid to do things like that.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just try it? Renaming is easy to undo. =)

But it should be safe to do. As far as I know, the solution file name is not used anywhere (unlike the project file names, which are used in the solution).

Answer (score 0):

Renaming the solution should be a safe operation as the solution file is just a "repository" to keep track of all the resource belong to the solution (Project,etc)
If you are using a source control software it is a different matter

Answer (score 0):

You can do that without any problem if you're doing that inside Visual Studio. If you are not using TFS SourceControl this can be done directly from the file system as well. 
Things are different for projects. You can still do that from inside Visual Studio, but if you just rename the csproj file, the project name doesn't change and all the references in the solutions containing the project will be broken. Furthermore the name of the dll or the exe are not changed and the same applies to the default namespace, and this is something that you could dislike.